# Is it possible to use Windows Speech Recognition built in commands without its shared interface?

Tags: c#, windows, speech-recognition, sapi

I wanted to know whether it is possible to use Windows Speech Recognition built in Commands without the shared interface of WSR. I'm using SAPI in C# programming Language.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an in process recognizer. So searching for SpInprocRecognizer should give you more information about it.

When you create your recognizer you should do something like:

```
private ISpeechRecoContext RecoContext;
private SpInprocRecognizer Recognizer;
private ISpeechRecoGrammar Grammar;

// Create a new recognizer
Recognizer = new SpInprocRecognizer();
// Create a recognition context.
RecoContext = Recognizer.CreateRecoContext();
```

Then you recognize as normal, and you won't see the windows recognizer GUI.